# Angularjs directive passing variables to sub-directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angularjs project, I've run into a problem with directive nesting and variable passing.

I made a directive header:

```
.directive('header', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'header.tpl.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.showDescriptions = false;
            scope.expandDescriptions = function() {
                ...
                scope.showDescriptions = !scope.showDescriptions;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the template, use another directive:

```
<div class="description" votable show-vote="showDescriptions"></div>
```

and the votable directive:

```
.directive('votable', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            showVote: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'votable.tpl.html',
    }
}
```

in votable.html:

```
<div class="vote" ng-show="showVote"></div>
```

When I run this, the vote icon should be hidden to start, but it is showing.

I have another element + directive combo:

```
<div expandable expand="expandDescriptions" ng-show="showDescriptions"></div>
```

This directive is hidden at the start, but after expanding, it cannot collapse even though it's toggling the showDescriptions variable.

Do I need to do something special to pass a variable from the scope of a directive into the scope of a sub-directive?

Comment: Your example works in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tasnimreza/kuSUS/2/

Comment: I guess I simplified the code a little bit too much. I'll beef it up later when I have more time.

One problem I noticed is at link time of the sub-directive, the showDescriptions attribute is not parsed as a variable, but passed to the sub-directive as the string "showDescriptions"

Answer (score 2):

With nested directives, the child directive will have its data bound before the **link** function for the parent directive is run. If you need to have some value in the parent scope available in order for the child directive to render properly, you need to bind that in the **preLink** of the parent directive. Add a compile function such that it returns your **preLink** function, and it should be fine, like so:

```
compile: function() {
    return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.showDescriptions = false;
            scope.expandDescriptions = function() {
            ...
            scope.showDescriptions = !scope.showDescriptions;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just figured it out, yet I can't really explain it. The variable passing through the scopes was somehow getting interrupted by a transition CSS class with    display: block !important;. removing the css class (which had nothing to do with the directives, made scope work as I would expect.